# How to change the default format date is 01-01-1970 to null (PHP)?

Tags: php, html

Because my date data in my database is null, and its showing 01-01-1970, how to make the data still null not default ?

```
<td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($us->tgl)) ?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0maN.jpg)

i just want the date in field is null not default 01-01-1970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a validation before formatting the date.

```
<td><?php echo !isset($us->tgl) ? '' : date('d-m-Y', strtotime($us->tgl)) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an if-else to check for null date value from the db

In plain English along the lines of…

if (db col value == ‘’)
Then “” (empty column)
Else
“”strtotime(row[‘dbdatevalue’])””(format row in          required date format)